# Mechanize redirect / Nokogiri (noob using mechanize)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I have something that looks like this:

```
def self.foo
  agent = Mechanize.new
  form  = agent.get("link/to/form/url")

  form.form_with(:name => "form_name") do |f|
    f.field_with(:name => "input_name").value = "random_value"
    agent.form.forms[0].submit
    agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
  end
  self.bar
end

def self.bar
  #may need to pass variable for agent here?
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(need redirect object!))
  doc.css(".random_class").text
end
```

After I call the class method `foo`, it successfully finds the form, fills in the input and submits it. However, when it finishes and calls `bar`, I'm stuck.

I have not found a way to successfully pass in a Mechanize object that is the resulting page's HTML after the redirect post form submission to test and see if I have captured the correct page, and parse the CSS with Nokogiri.

Any there Mechanize wizards out there that have any suggestions?

Comment: What is `Nokogiri::::HTML`? You obviously didn't try to run that code. Do you mean `Nokogiri::HTML`?

Comment: Yes a typo, that wasn't a copy and paste...

Answer (score 0):

Your `agent` variable is local to the `foo` method, so `bar` doesn't see it. You probably want to use a class variable, e.g. `@agent`. I'm not sure why you are creating class methods like this. If you provide the source to the class, and a little more description of why you are doing it that way, you may get better advice.